# Does Bohr van Leeuwen theorem not exclude the possibility of explaining paramagnetism classically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, partition-function

We have the Bohr-van Leeuwen theorem which tells that magnetism cannot be explained classically. The proof is simple; it turns out that classically the partition function is independent of the magnetic vector potential and therefore, the free energy is independent of the magnetic field which proves that there cannot be magnetization.

But we have a classical Langevin theory of paramagnetism where the partition function is not independent of $B$, and thus we get a magnetization. So how can we say that magnetism cannot be explained classically? Doesn't the Bohr van Leeuwen theorem fail here?

Comment: There is this [closely related question (and answer)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/444482).

Comment: @YvanVelenik That question was about diamagnetism. This is about paramagnetism. In particular the Langevin theory of paramagnetism. Proof of the Bohr-von Leeuwen theorem is based on showing that the classical partition function is independent of B. That completes the proof. But for classical theory of paramagnetism, the partition function is not independent of B. Does that mean paramagnetism can be explained classically?

Comment: The answer is that, citing J. H. Van Vleck, *"when Langevin assumed that the magnetic moment of the atom or molecule had a fixed value $\mu$, he was quantizing the system without realizing it."* If you do not **assume** the existence of a permanent magnetic moment, but try to derive it from the motion of electrons inside the atoms, then this is doomed to fail (classically), precisely because of the Bohr-van Leeuwen theorem. In other words, Langevin theory is *not* a classical theory, but a kind of semi-classical theory.

Comment: See, for instance, [this recent review paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.11291.pdf) for a discussion.

Comment: See this other related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121362/does-the-bohr-van-leeuwen-theorem-also-apply-to-ferromagnetism

Comment: @YvanVelenik Both your comment and reference are useful. Can you put it as a short answer?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Done. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to answer your question is that, citing J. H. Van Vleck,

> when Langevin assumed that the magnetic moment of the atom or molecule had a fixed value $\mu$, he was quantizing the system without realizing it.

If you do not assume the existence of a permanent magnetic moment, but try to derive it from the motion of electrons inside the atoms, then this is doomed to fail (classically), precisely because of the Bohr-van Leeuwen theorem. In other words, Langevin theory is not a classical theory, but a kind of semi-classical theory.

This is discussed, for instance, in [this recent review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11291).

Comment: [Electrons also have a permanent magnetic field around them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/615652/46708) and this fact is obscured by the fact that we have mentally assigned only the electric charge to the electron, but not the magnetic dipole. We measured, calculated and fixed the electrons magnetic moment (NIST reference). It is a constant value.

Answer (score 2):

The Bohr-von-Leeuwen theorem applies to the absence of classical  *diamagnetism*  i.e to the magnetic effects on the classical theory of electron motion. On the other hand *paramagnetism* arsises from the field-induced alignment of the electrons *instrinsic magnetic moment*, an effect ignored in Bohr-von-Leeuwen.  The electron's intrinsic magnetic moment is a  quantum effect accounted for by the Dirac equation.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Why do you say that "paramagnetism arsises from the field-induced alignment of the electrons intrinsic magnetic moment"? Langevin theory only assumes a $\vec{\mu}\cdot{\vec B}$ interaction without any need to assume the origin of ${\vec \mu}$. Why the ${\vec \mu}$ vector in Langevin theory cannot have classical origin?

Comment: It *could* have a classical origin, but it does not. In any case, it has nothing to do with Bohr-von-Leeuwen.

Comment: Are you saying that BVL theorem does not exclude the possibility of explaining paramagnetism classically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the van Leeuwen-Bohr theorem isn't omnipotent. It assumes a specific scenario using classical physics, where charged particles without a magnetic moment in a finite region of space have Boltzmannian distribution of velocities, i.e. for every direction the opposite one is equally probable. Even on the boundary of the region, which is necessary for the theorem to hold.

If the particles themselves carry magnetic moment or if they move in a preferred direction, theorem's assumptions are not satisfied and the result does not hold.

Even if the particles do not have magnetic moment, they can still create magnetic moment by their motion. Consider weakly interacting charged particles moving in circles in external magnetic field. The motion is such that the set of particles behaves as diamagnetic body. This is possible because the particles' velocities aren't Boltzmannian; on the boundary of the region where the particles are, there is a preferred direction of motion consistent with the circling motion in the magnetic field.

From EM theory we know we can attribute to magnetic bodies a surface magnetization current. One way (Ampere's theory) to explain this current microscopically is that charged particles in the layer of space containing the body surface have a preferred direction in which they move. So the model of magnetized body can be classical but not assume Boltzmannian distribution for all particles. Not every system has to be Boltzmannian.