# How did magnets first come about?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Physics concepts state that in order to turn ferrous (or other magnetic) material magnetic, you need to stroke it with a magnet. Okay, but for the first magnet, we didn't have another magnet to stroke it with.

The other way is to induce it with an electric current in a coil wrapped around the magnet. But you can't produce current without a magnet?! So again, the first magnet couldn't be made with that?!

Answer (score 4):

Natural magnets, called "lodestones",  were found  in  iron ores (magnetite)  from the ancient region of Magnesia, hence the name "Magnet".

This I knew before reading your question.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Discovery_and_development) anwers a question that I had never really considered:

"The other question is how lodestones get magnetized. The Earth's magnetic field at 0.5 gauss is too weak to magnetize a lodestone by itself. The leading theory is that lodestones are magnetized by the strong magnetic fields surrounding lightning bolts. This is supported by the observation that they are mostly found near the surface of the Earth, rather than buried at great depth."

Comment: Do magnets "lose" their own magnetism if used for making magnets or in solenoids? Is there something like a "conservation of magnetic energy" in physics?

Comment: No there is no conservation law.  There is the Einstein-de-Haas effect, but that connects magnetism to angular momentum conservation, not  to "magnetism conservation".

Comment: So if I make a 100 magnets, I can feel safe that I did no harm to the first one? That is, ignoring obvious faults, e.g. hammering, heating etc.

Comment: @ElFlea Correct, the magnetism  from the first one doesn't get used up when making new magnets. The energy required comes from the kinetic energy you use to do the stroking.

Comment: Several years ago, the pole which supports my outside TV antenna was struck by lightning. A TV inside the house and just a few feet from the pole survived the induced voltage pulse in the household wiring, but it had to be de-magnitized before it would give a decent picture.  (Other electronic devices on the far side of the house did not survive.)  My de-magnitizer is a heavy, hand held, coil.  I pluged it into an AC outlet and moved it over the surface of the afflicted TV to get normal operation.  I'm assuming that the TV was magnetized by the field produced by the current pulse in the pole.

Answer (score 2):

See [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite) Magnetite $(\textrm{Fe}_3 \textrm{O}_4)$ is ferromagnetic and can be magnetized.  Naturally occurring, already magnetized, versions of this material are called lodestone.

How lodestones itself gets magnetized is still somewhat of a mystery as far as I can tell, though the question is addressed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodestone)

Comment: Do magnets "lose" their own magnetism if used for making magnets or in solenoids? Is there something like a "conservation of magnetic energy" in physics?

Comment: When you use a magnet to magnetize another material, what you are doing is orienting the magnetic domains that already exist in the unmagnetized material.  In other words, an unmagnetized piece of iron is unmagnetized because it just does not have all it little internal magnets pointing in the same direction.  Placing it in a magnetic field helps to orient the domains in roughly all the same direction.  Doing this will have no effect on the magnet doing the magnetization since you are just reinforcing the field in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the *elect*ron indicates that these subatomic particles have an ***electric*** **field** around them.

Electrons also have a permanent ***magnetic*** **field** around them and this fact is obscured by the fact that we have mentally assigned only the electric charge to the electron, but not the magnetic dipole. We measured, calculated and fixed the electrons magnetic moment ([NIST reference](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?muem)). It is a constant value.

However, we are not prepared to conclude that a macroscopic magnetic field in permanent magnets is nothing more than the sum of the aligned magnetic dipoles of the electrons involved. We only explain the occurrence of magnetic fields by electric currents. Which is fine for inductive processes, but unnecessary for permanent magnets.

As you know, permanent magnets lose their magnetisation above the Currie points. In return, materials acquire a macroscopic magnetic field at cryogenic temperatures.
This can be explained by the dependence of the chaotic motion and oscillations of subatomic particles on temperature. At certain temperatures, a self-alignment of the magnetic dipoles of the electrons occurs. This process can be favoured by the transition from a liquid to a solid phase. Or, in the case of Bose-Einstein condensates, from a gaseous phase to the BEC state.

> the first magnet couldn't be made with that?

You are able to "build" a magnet yourself. Take a material with unpaired electrons (with 1, 3, 5, ... electrons in the outer orbital) It works best with some [rare earths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare-earth_element). If you make them hot, they lose their magnetic properties. If you cool them down, the electrons involved align themselves through their magnetic dipoles.

In practice, such compounds (materials made of different elements) are ground into a fine powder and then pressed, at the same time an external magnetic field is applied. This aligns more electrons and the artificial magnet becomes stronger. But be careful, such magnets are under strong tension. Do not expose them to shocks, otherwise they will break explosively.